# How to create multiple instances of a model with factoryboy in django?

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, factory-boy

How do I create multiple instances of this Resource?  When I try to do it, I get the same instance created.  I do tend to end up with it creating multiple users, but only one Resource.

Here is the factory declaration

```py
class ResourceFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Resource

    client = factory.SubFactory(
        ClientFactory,
    )
    user = factory.SubFactory(
        UserFactory,
    )
    start_date = Faker("date_time")
    end_date = None
    department = Faker("sentence", nb_words=2)
    title = Faker("sentence", nb_words=4)
    custom_data_field = {"fake": "data"}
```

This is roughly how I have been trying to do things.  I want all resources associated with the same client.  At this point, I got the client from the database, because I was getting random errors, and that seemed to fix those errors, at least.

```py
client = ClientFactory()
db_client = Client.objects.get(id=client.id)
resources = [ResourceFactory(client=db_client) for i in range(5)]
```

if I run `len(Resource.objects.all())` at this point, it comes back as `1`.  How do I create 5 separate resources in the database, all associated with the same client?

Comment: Can you try with `ResourceFactory.create_batch(5, client=db_client)`

Comment: I tried that.  It does the same thing.  `resources` shows 5 elements to the array, but they all contain the same exact data, and `len(Resource.objects.all())` says there is only 1 result.

Comment: Try using factory.LazyAttribute and factory.LazyAttributeSequence from factory-boy

Comment: Please tell me your `random errors`, `Resource` model source code and `Client` model source code.

Comment: Sorry, this was a project I was working on 2 1/2 years ago.  I'm not even sure which project it was, or how or if I ultimately got around this issue.